# Adding sub-directory to "View/Shared" folder in ASP.Net MVC and calling the view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm currently developing a site using ASP.Net MVC3 with Razor. Inside the "View/Shared" folder, I want to add a subfolder called "Partials" where I can place all of my partial views (for the sake of organizing the site better.

I can do this without a problem as long as I always reference the "Partials" folder when calling the views (using Razor):

```
@Html.Partial("Partials/{ViewName}")
```

My question is if there is a way to add the "Partials" folder to the list that .Net goes through when searching for a view, this way I can call my view without having to reference the "Partials" folder, like so:

```
@Html.Partial("{ViewName}")
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Solved this. To add the "Shared/Partials" sub directory I created to the list of locations searched when trying to locate a Partial View in Razor using:

```
@Html.Partial("{NameOfView}")
```

First create a view engine with RazorViewEngine as its base class and add your view locations as follows. Again, I wanted to store all of my partial views in a "Partials" subdirectory that I created within the default "Views/Shared" directory created by MVC.

```
public class RDDBViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    private static readonly string[] NewPartialViewFormats = 
    { 
        "~/Views/{1}/Partials/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/Shared/Partials/{0}.cshtml"
    };

    public RDDBViewEngine()
    {
        base.PartialViewLocationFormats = base.PartialViewLocationFormats.Union(NewPartialViewFormats).ToArray();
    }       

}
```

Note that {1} in the location format is the Controller name and {0} is the name of the view.

Then add that view engine to the MVC ViewEngines.Engines Collection in the Application_Start() method in your global.asax:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RDDBViewEngine());
```

Comment: I wanted to do the same thing in my project.  Thanks for the clear solution.

Comment: +1 Thanks. That is really easy doing that. And the proper way with creating a reusable class :)

Comment: Where do you add the class "RDDBViewEngine" that you made in step 2?

Comment: I created a new .cs file and then added the class to my main {Project}.Models namespace. In VS, just right click on your Models directory, click Add->Class and name the class FooViewEngine. You'll get the stubbed out class that you can copy the above code into.

Comment: Area is available as well as {2} in the PartialViewLocationFormats.

Comment: @lamarant, See my answer below for Areas.

Comment: For MVC 5, just put @Html.Partial("Partial/myPartial.cshtml")

Answer (score 31):

Thank you for your answers.  This has organized my Shared folder, but why do you create a new type of view engine? I just made a new `RazorViewEngine`, set it's `PartialViewLocationFormats` and added it to the list of `ViewEngines`.

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine
{
    PartialViewLocationFormats = new string[]
    {
        "~/Views/{1}/Partials/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/Shared/Partials/{0}.cshtml"
    }
});
```

Comment: Creating your own class will allow you to reuse it in the future instead of remembering to handwrite those string literals every time.

Comment: Both approaches will work, and I guess each has it's own pros & cons. To me this is the better answer because we are not changing the behaviour already available in the `RazorViewEngine`.

Comment: Note that you can just as easily run the code in this answer from a Helper method, that captures this just the once all the same, rather than building an additional class with just this one detail in it.

Answer (score 20):

It´s nice to custom the view engine, but if you just want to have a subfolder por partials you don´t need that much...

Just use the full path to the partial view, as done for the Layout View:

```
@Html.Partial("/Views/Shared/Partial/myPartial.cshtml")
```

Hope it helps someone...

Comment: Thanks, really simple and WORKING solution!

Comment: For MVC 5, just put @Html.Partial("Partial/myPartial.cshtml")

Answer (score 14):

If you are doing this in ASP.NET Core, simple go to the Startup class, under `ConfigureServices` method, and put

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddRazorOptions(opt => {
        opt.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Views/{1}/Partials/{0}.cshtml");
        opt.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Views/Shared/Partials/{0}.cshtml");
    });
```

Comment: And for those who aren't sure what the {0} and {1} placeholders represent, {1} would be the controller-name and {0} would be the view-name.  And I would add that instead of hard-coding the '.cshtml' extension you could use the `ViewLocationFormats.ViewExtension` property.

Answer (score 7):

I've updated lamarant's excellent answer to include Areas:

```
public class RDDBViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    private static readonly string[] NewPartialViewFormats =
    {
        "~/Views/{1}/Partials/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/Shared/Partials/{0}.cshtml"
    };

    private static List<string> AreaRegistrations;

    public RDDBViewEngine()
    {
        AreaRegistrations = new List<string>();

        BuildAreaRegistrations();

        base.PartialViewLocationFormats = base.PartialViewLocationFormats.Union(NewPartialViewFormats).ToArray();
        base.PartialViewLocationFormats = base.PartialViewLocationFormats.Union(areaRegistrations).ToArray();
    }

    private static void BuildAreaRegistrations()
    {
        string[] areaNames = RouteTable.Routes.OfType<Route>()
            .Where(d => d.DataTokens != null && d.DataTokens.ContainsKey("area"))
            .Select(r => r.DataTokens["area"].ToString()).ToArray();

        foreach (string areaName in areaNames)
        {
            AreaRegistrations.Add("~/Areas/" + areaName + "/Views/Shared/Partials/{0}.cshtml");
            AreaRegistrations.Add("~/Areas/" + areaName + "/Views/{1}/Partials/{0}.cshtml");
        }
    }
}
```

Then don't forget to include in your application start:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...

        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RDDBViewEngine()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I did this but I'm getting an `ArgumentNullException` on the `virtualPath`, what am I wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You can also update the partialview-location-formats of the registered RazorViewEngine.
Place the below code in Application_Start in Global.asax.

```
 RazorViewEngine razorEngine = ViewEngines.Engines.OfType<RazorViewEngine>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (razorEngine != null)
        {
            string[] newPartialViewFormats = new[] { 
                    "~/Views/{1}/Partials/{0}.cshtml",
                    "~/Views/Shared/Partials/{0}.cshtml"
            };
            razorEngine.PartialViewLocationFormats =
                razorEngine.PartialViewLocationFormats.Union(newPartialViewFormats).ToArray();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create register your own view engine that derives from whatever view engine your are using (Webforms/Razor) and specify whatever locations you want in the constructor or just add them to the list of already existing locations:

```
this.PartialViewLocationFormats = viewLocations;
```

Then in application start you would add your view engine like so:
 `ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new MyViewEngineWithPartialPath());`

Comment: You don't need to inherit the class.