# Defining more "Shared" folders in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

Is it possible to define more folders for ASP.NET MVC to search for Views or Partials?

For example, if I browse to /Home/Index and the Index action returns View(), ASP.NET MVC will look at the following locations:

- ~/Views/Home/Index.aspx
- ~/Views/Home/Index.ascx
- ~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
- ~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
- ~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
- ~/Views/Home/Index.vbhtml
- ~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
- ~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml

I want to create another folder, say ~/Views/PartivalViews/, that will be searched.

Obviously I'm looking for this as a tidy way to store my PartialViews.

Comment: Check here

[Adding sub-directory to “View/Shared” folder in ASP.Net MVC and calling the view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973000/adding-sub-directory-to-view-shared-folder-in-asp-net-mvc-and-calling-the-view)

Comment: Check this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909794/how-to-change-default-view-location-scheme-in-asp-net-mvc][1]

Hope will help.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909794/how-to-change-default-view-location-scheme-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write a [`custom view engine`](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/06/27/view-engine-with-dynamic-view-location.aspx) where you could specify additional folders where ASP.NET MVC will look for views.

The idea here is to write a class deriving from `RazorViewEngine` and in its constructor set the various properties such as:

- AreaViewLocationFormats
- AreaMasterLocationFormats
- AreaPartialViewLocationFormats
- ViewLocationFormats
- MasterLocationFormats
- PartialViewLocationFormats

Here are the default values that you could feel free to override:

```
public RazorViewEngine(IViewPageActivator viewPageActivator) : base(viewPageActivator)
{
    base.AreaViewLocationFormats = new string[] { "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml", "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml", "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml" };
    base.AreaMasterLocationFormats = new string[] { "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml", "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml", "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml" };
    base.AreaPartialViewLocationFormats = new string[] { "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml", "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml", "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml" };
    base.ViewLocationFormats = new string[] { "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml", "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml", "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml" };
    base.MasterLocationFormats = new string[] { "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml", "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml", "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml" };
    base.PartialViewLocationFormats = new string[] { "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml", "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml", "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml" };
    base.FileExtensions = new string[] { "cshtml", "vbhtml" };
}
```

And then simply register your custom view engine in `Application_Start`:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new MyRazorViewEngine());
```

In this example I have removed all other default view engines (WebForms and Razor) before registering our custom one.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I found some nice instructions on how to do it here:

http://coding-in.net/mvc-3-organize-your-partial-views/

Answer (score 0):

If you wonder how to proceed from Darin answer above, this is how I implemented it.
All credit goes to Darin and Owen.

I basically wanted to place all my Partial Views under `Views/Controller/Shared` folder. So I only replaced the "PartialViewLocationFormats" property of the "RazorViewEngine". Added "`~/Views/{1}/Shared/{0}.cshtml`" as the first element in the list, so that ViewEngine will look at the `"Views/Controller/Shared`" folder first.

Then as Darin explained above in the global.asax, clear the existing view engines and add the new one.

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CustomRazorViewEngine());
```

Hope this helps someone.

```
public class CustomRazorViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
    {
        public CustomRazorViewEngine()
        {
            var newLocationFormat = new[]
                                    {
                                        "~/Views/{1}/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
                                        "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", 
                                        "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml", 
                                        "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml", 
                                        "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
                                    };

            PartialViewLocationFormats = newLocationFormat;
        }

    }
```