# Is it possible to have multiple Shared folders in MVC, and execute a RenderPartial to a Partial View in the other shared folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In MVC5, I know you can have a `Shared` folder under `Views` and then use the `RenderPartial` to render in partial views.

Is there only ever one `Shared` folder for the whole website?, or is it possible to have multiple 'Shared' areas?

For instance, I have the following structure on my website:-

> \Views
>
> \Views\Shared
>
> \Controllers
>
> \Models
>
> \Identity
>
> \Identity\Views
>
> \Identity\Controllers
>
> \Identity\Models

I was wondering if it would also be possible for the `Identity` folder to have its own `Shared` folder as well, that RenderPartial would also work for?

If this is possible, can I render a `PartialView` from this other `Shared` folder?  I had tried this but wasn't successful - even if I directly reference the View using the `tilde ~` approach, but it doesn't seem to like running throwing an `exception`.  However if I put the `PartialView` in my `\Views\Shared` folder then everything works.

Comment: You just need to add 'Identity' as Area. So you'll have separate views, controllers and views and finally separate shared folder for each Area :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include your directories in the ViewEngine by adding following code in **Global.asax**  in `Application_Start()` event:

```
RazorViewEngine razorEngine = ViewEngines.Engines.OfType<RazorViewEngine>().FirstOrDefault();
if (razorEngine != null)
{
  string[] newPartialViewFormats = new[] 
          { 
            "~/Indentity/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Identity/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
          };

  razorEngine.PartialViewLocationFormats = razorEngine.PartialViewLocationFormats.Union(newPartialViewFormats).ToArray();
 }
```

Now ViewEngine will find the view in **View/Shared** and also in **Identity/Views/Shared**

You can refer [**this link**](http://blogs.msmvps.com/luisabreu/blog/2008/09/17/the-mvc-platform-view-engines/) and also refer this [**SO Post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973000/adding-sub-directory-to-view-shared-folder-in-asp-net-mvc-and-calling-the-view).

Answer (score 1):

When rendering `PartialView`s from other folder rather than the default `View` folder, you must provide the full path plus the file type:

**Ex:**

```
@Html.Partial("~/Identity/Views/myviewname.cshtml")
```

The way you are doing, looks like you are trying to implement an already existent functionality named Areas.

You should take a look here:

[Walk through: Organizing an ASP.NET MVC Application using Areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(VS.100).aspx)

Comment: Perfect.  Thankyou.  I had not put in the `.cshtml`, I would had thought that would be automatic.

Comment: So I assume its only one Shared folder for a website, considering we have to specify a full path to any other partials views used?

Comment: @Johnny you can add your directory in ViewEngine :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973000/adding-sub-directory-to-view-shared-folder-in-asp-net-mvc-and-calling-the-view by default it looks in Views directory, but we can add more directories in which Engine should find view