# execute handler before the view is rendered in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to manipulate the view that eventually MVC is going to render at run time.

For example at `HomeConttroller` I do this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     return View();
}
```

asp.net mvc has decided to render `~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml` i want to change it to something like "~/en/Views/Homem/Index.cshtml".
update:
i do`not want to use the View(string path) overload.

i mean i want to change the path at the last moment.
this question is not a duplicate so please dont vote for closing when you havent undertand the question ... pff

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC How to specify which folder the View pages reside in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799838/asp-net-mvc-how-to-specify-which-folder-the-view-pages-reside-in)

Comment: check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575397/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-shared-folders-in-mvc-and-execute-a-renderparti and also this: http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2014/10/aspnet-mvc-adding-custom-direcotry-for.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have multiple Shared folders in MVC, and execute a RenderPartial to a Partial View in the other shared folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575397/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-shared-folders-in-mvc-and-execute-a-renderparti)

Answer (score 1):

> I want to change it at run time to some thing like
>   ~/Views/en/Home/Index.cshtml. Is this possible?

Sure, you can specify the view to be rendered using [`this overload`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460352(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     return View("~/Views/en/Home/Index.cshtml");
}
```