# Adding sub-directory to “View/Shared” folder in ASP MVC core and calling the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have some problem with adding subfolder to /Views/Shared in project.
Here is my current structure:

> /Views/Shared/AreasNavs/{0}.cshtml

From the web I found some solutions:

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(o =>
{               
      o.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Views/Shared/AreasNavs/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
});
```

...and this solution from [Adding sub-directory to “View/Shared” folder in ASP.Net MVC and calling the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973000/adding-sub-directory-to-view-shared-folder-in-asp-net-mvc-and-calling-the-view)

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddRazorOptions(opt => {
        opt.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Views/{1}/Partials/{0}.cshtml");
        opt.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Views/Shared/Partials/{0}.cshtml");
    });
```

but nothing is work.

**Update.** this problem is related to the appeal from the Area

Have you any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I`ve just run into the same problem. The issue is related to area registration. Instead of

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(o =>
{               
      o.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Views/Shared/AreasNavs/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
});
```

use view location for areas

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(o =>
{               
      o.AreaViewLocationFormats.Add("/Views/Shared/AreasNavs/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
});
```